# IntelliJ git integration tips and tricks

Tags: java, git, intellij-idea

I actually ignored the git integration that IntelliJ has and I was recently frustrated with the diff tools that git comes with by default, I noticed how intellij has a very nice way of seeing the history for a given file, and comparing previous versions etc.

What are some cool/useful git integration tips and tricks you like with IntelliJ?

1. I would like to see some keyboard shortcuts, like if I am on a file, I want to quicky open up the history view or compare with the last commigted file.
2. Is it possible to compare commits? (not just a single file)

BTW, what diff tool does IntelliJ use by default, it's pretty good!

Answer (score 6):

You can view IntelliJ IDEA's [default keymap reference card](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/docs/IntelliJIDEA_ReferenceCard.pdf) to see what's available starting out.

I don't believe there is a default keyboard shortcut assigned to showing the current file history, but you can specifically assign a shortcut to show file history:

> Settings → Keymap → (in the search box on the right type: "history" to narrow the options) → assign your desired keyboard shortcut to "Git: Show History"

While it is definitely possible to compare various revisions of a file from different commits, I'm not sure what else you would want to do to compare commits beyond the scope of a single file, but when reviewing commits, you can view all of the changes in the commit, showing all the diffs, one file at a time.

As far as their diff tool is concerned, I believe it was internally developed and is part of their [version control](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/version_control.html) featureset.

Comment: so how can I compare 2 changesets, and then drill down to compare a file against another?